# Fetching Images through Cloud Code

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I've been scratching my head over this for a while. What am I doing wrong? Your help is much appreciated :)

I've tried many different image codes, but I think it's a promise issue I'm seeing. With the code below I only see the "Start of loop" log message.
If I move the results push outside the promise structure to underneath then I see the Stage log messages, albeit after all the Start of loops have printed (hence why I put the push in the then function).

```
Parse.Cloud.job("fetchjson", function(request, status) {

var url = 'some json url';

Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({url: url}).then(function(httpResponse){
    //var Image = require("parse-image");
    var Seeds = Parse.Object.extend("Seeds");
    var jsonobj = JSON.parse(httpResponse.text);

    var results = [];
    // do NOT iterate arrays with `for... in loops`
    for(var i = 0; i < jsonobj.seeds.length; i++){
        var seed = new Seed();
        var a = new Seed(jsonobj.seeds[i]);
        console.log("Start of loop");

        Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({url: a.get("image") }).then(function(response) {
          console.log("Stage 1");
          //var file = new Parse.File('thumb.jpg', { base64: response.buffer.toString('base64', 0, response.buffer.length) });
          //return file.save();
          return "hi"
        }).then(function(thumb) {
          console.log("Stage 2");
          //a.set("imageFile", thumb);  
          //a.set("viewsInt", parseInt(a.get("views")));
        }, function(error) {
          console.log("Error occurred :(");
        }).then(function(){
          results.push(seed.save(a)); // add to aggregate
        });

    }
    // .when waits for all promises
    Parse.Promise.when(results).then(function(data){
        status.success("All saved");
    });


  }, function(error) {
    console.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
    status.error("Failed");
});
});
```